# pure css conditional menu: hide level1 info on level2 hover

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a pure CSS drop down menu with info area.

My Problem is, that i want to show the info of the first level but hide it when you hover over the second level.
Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Jjfj/2/)

The Problem is, that I don't know how to hide the first level info
[image: Menu Bug]

I know that I can't access the parent, so I tried to make it conditional, like:

```
menu-level1 > ul > li:not(.menu-level2):hover > .menu-info
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

How do I have to write the condition to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm so happy that I finally understood what you meant, although via some difficulty.
And, i got happier when I got what you wanted to see :-)

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/5Jjfj/11/

**New css (very minor change):**

```
.menu-level1 > ul > li a:hover + .menu-info, .menu-info:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

**instead of:**

```
.menu-level1 > ul > li:hover > .menu-info, .menu-info:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: awesome^^ thank you very much, and I'm sorry for my vague question

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Jjfj/4/

```
.menu-level1 > ul > li:hover > .menu-info, .menu-info:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that i want to show the level1 info on level1 hover and hide the level1 info on level2 hover. In your example the level1 info is always hidden

Comment: The level1 info is still hidden on hover